# Cryptopp.dll Access violation reading location 0x74736554

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cryptography, crypto++

I am trying to use cryptopp, the below code cause access violation at the stringsource function. What could be the possible cause of this ? I have previously run the similar code with little difference successfully.

AesHelper.cpp

```
#include "dll.h"
#include "AesHelper.h"

#include "aes.h"
using CryptoPP::AES;
#include "ccm.h"
using CryptoPP::CBC_Mode;

#include "filters.h"
using CryptoPP::StringSink;
using CryptoPP::StringSource;
using CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter;

#include "hex.h"
using CryptoPP::HexEncoder;
using CryptoPP::HexDecoder;

#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "osrng.h"
using CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool;

byte AesHelper::_key[AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
byte AesHelper::_iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE];

void AesHelper::encrypt(const char* str, char ** outIv, char ** encrypted )
{
    try
    {
        AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

        byte key[AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
        prng.GenerateBlock(key, sizeof(key));

        byte iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
        prng.GenerateBlock(iv, sizeof(iv));

        string cipher, encoded;
        string plain = "CBC Test Mode";

        CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption e;
        e.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv);

        // The StreamTransformationFilter removes
        //  padding as required.
        StreamTransformationFilter *stf = new StreamTransformationFilter(e,
                new StringSink(cipher),
                CryptoPP::BlockPaddingSchemeDef::ZEROS_PADDING
            );

        StringSource s(plain, true, stf); // This line cause Access Violation

        StreamTransformationFilter filter(e);
        filter.Put((const byte*)plain.data(), plain.size());
        filter.MessageEnd();

        const size_t ret = filter.MaxRetrievable();
        cipher.resize(ret);
        filter.Get((byte*)cipher.data(), cipher.size());

        //encode the cipher to hexadecimal
        StringSource(cipher, true,
        new HexEncoder(
                new StringSink(encoded)
            ) // HexEncoder
        ); // StringSource


        //set the output parameter
        outIv = (char**)_iv;
        encrypted = (char**)cipher.c_str();
    }
    catch(const CryptoPP::Exception& e)
    {
        cerr << "exception : " << e.what() << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

}
```

Error

> Unhandled exception at 0x550714CA (cryptopp.dll) in
>   PaymentManager.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x74736554.
>
> > cryptopp.dll!memcpy(unsigned char * dst, unsigned char * src, unsigned long count) Line 188 Unknown

**UPDATE :** 
Problem solved after making both DLL and Exe program to "Release". But now there's new problem.
on this line, the problem also in stringsource function

```
StringSource(cipher, true,
            new HexEncoder(
                    new StringSink(encoded)
                ) // HexEncoder
            ); // StringSource
```

error

> PaymentManager.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

The program stop at

```
void __cdecl _free_base (void * pBlock) {

        int retval = 0;


        if (pBlock == NULL)
            return;

        RTCCALLBACK(_RTC_Free_hook, (pBlock, 0));

        retval = HeapFree(_crtheap, 0, pBlock); // program stop at this line
        if (retval == 0)
        {
            errno = _get_errno_from_oserr(GetLastError());
        } }
```

Comment: I had this same problem in another form. For me the Cryptopp.dll was compiled with 1 Byte alignment and my app was using a different alignment. The answer @Adam Rosenfield provided resolved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know this library, but as I see `StringSource` get `std::string` as first parameter. In this case you should be absolutely sure, that both DLL and your program compiled and linked with exactly the same STL, with exactly the same compilers and their options

Comment: Hi I think this maybe the possible issue, I am using visual studio 2012 express. I am new to this linking process, may I know specifically what compiler options ? Thanks

Comment: Compiler options should be simply the same when you compile DLL and executable. Maybe you compiled DLL as `Release` and exe as `Debug` ? If yes - that's an answer

Comment: Hi, thanks, yes this is the answer, my dll is in debug, the app in release, so I set both to release. Thanks, but now am facing new problem. I have update my question at the above. Can help shade some light ?

Comment: This can happen because you're allocating memory in exe and DLL tries to deallocate it. Read attentively an article from Adam Rosenfield's answer (Allocating and freeing memory across module boundaries). As a simple solution I'll recommend to include sources from DLL into exe's project. It'll solve all (oh, not... let's say many))) problems

Comment: omg, I have actually use static linking to the project without the DLL, and in order to be without dll, I have to exclude this line
#include "dll.h" . Now it's working :) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

0x74736554 is hex for the four ASCII characters `"tseT"` (big-endian) or `"Test"` (little-endian)—the latter of which is exactly the bytes at indices 4-7 of your `string plain`.  The fact that the `StringSource` constructor is trying to read that address suggests that your executable and the DLL disagree on what a `std::string` looks like.  In particular, the library is dereferencing the memory address at offset 4 from the object you pass it, but the object you pass it doesn't have a valid pointer value there.

In other words, the `string` you're passing (or possibly some sub-object of it) looks like this in memory:

```
Offset    0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7
       +------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+--
Value  | 0x43 | 0x42 | 0x43 | 0x20 | 0x54 | 0x65 | 0x73 | 0x74 | ...
       | 'C'  | 'B'  | 'C'  | ' '  | 'T'  | 'e'  | 's'  | 't'  | ...
       +------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+--
```

But, the library is treating it like this:

```
Offset    0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7
       +------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+--
Value  |           ?????           | Pointer to character data | ...
       +------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+--
```

I figured this all out by just realizing that the address causing the fault consists entirely of ASCII values which match the values from the source code.

The cause of this is almost certainly your code and the library using different `std::string` implementations, which have different object layouts.  It's exactly the same problem as [Allocating and freeing memory across module boundaries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/15/755966.aspx).  In order to pass C++ objects between modules (i.e. the main executable and any DLLs it loads), both modules need to agree on how the object is laid out.  If the modules were compiled at different times, then you need to work harder to ensure that they're compiled against the same header files.

If you're compiling the DLL from source, then the easiest thing to do is to make sure that both the DLL and your executable are using the same C++ standard library implementation.  If you're using a DLL that's already been compiled by someone else, then you need to ask them or check the documentation to find the C++ standard library against which it was compiled, and then compile your executable against the same library.

If you can't do that, then the next best solution is to avoid passing C++ objects across module boundaries in **all** cases—use only APIs that take predefined data types (like integers and raw pointers) or data types defined in the DLL's header files.  This will completely avoid the problem, but it will also make your code much harder to write, since you can no longer pass or receive a `std::string`.

Comment: Hi I have the source code for that library, may I know if you can point me where can I set this STL in visual studio 2012 ? I am going to do research on this too. Thanks for your awesome answer, I have more understanding what's wrong now.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Boris and Adam's answers, I've seen this cause a problem on Linux (I realize you are on Windows):

```
    StringSource(cipher, true,
    new HexEncoder(
            new StringSink(encoded)
        ) // HexEncoder
    ); // StringSource
```

Anonymous declarations are legal C/C++. But a particular version of GCC (circa 4.3 or 4.4 or 4.5) would begin running the destructors too soon in the generated code. I was talking to Jonathan Wakely about it back in 2011, but I was never able to figure out the cause. Here was the thread that caused m to start looking at it: [Running the RSA samples and some installation issues](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cryptopp-users/kzFQFHDioQw).

The work around was simply to:

```
    StringSource ss(cipher, true,
    new HexEncoder(
            new StringSink(encoded)
        ) // HexEncoder
    ); // StringSource
```